# Can not display JTable in JFrame at button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to add JTable at run time at click of a button(SEARCH button) in my application. The table was successfully displayed in a different program but when I tried to add code in actionPerformed method of the button here, the JTable is not displayed.

The GUI was created using netbeans GUI but I moved it to eclipse and adding the code for database.

The JTable displays data from database. The data is retrieved at button click. And the JTable should be displayed only at the button click containing that data on the same frame just below the buttons

The only issue is of JTable not being displayed. I tried using JScrollPane along with JPanel with no success. Tried other ways as well.

```
 '        

 package lib_ss;

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTable;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
 import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;


 public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public int id=0;

    public void getId(int i)
    {
        id=i;

    }


   JScrollPane  pane;

   TableColumn column;

   ResultSet rs=null;

   String col[]={"ID","NAME","AUTHOR","DEPT","Location","Publisher","Edition"};

   ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();

   DefaultTableModel model;

  JTable table;
  int k=0;
  private Connection con;

   public void connect()
   {

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","manhattan");
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame2
 */
public NewJFrame2() {
    initComponents();


       }

NewJFrame2(NewJFrame1 aThis) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}



/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    public void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();





    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Log Out");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        });
    getContentPane().add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(1060, 50, -1, -1));

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/lib_ss/mic1.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Search");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        });
    getContentPane().add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(619, 124, -1, -1));

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setText("Previous Records");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        });
    getContentPane().add(jButton3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(320, 124, 203, 56));

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/lib_ss/url1.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1230, 740));

    pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

public void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    NewJFrame1 frame = new NewJFrame1();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed



public void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","manhattan");

   PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from records where    stid=?");

     ps.setInt(6,id);

   //ps.setString(2,"bruce");



     rs=ps.executeQuery();

     if (rs.next()) 

       {            }


      }
    catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }



   //Search Button
   public void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
             int i=0;


                try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","manhattan");

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from books where name=? or author=?");

        ps.setString(1,"java");
          ps.setString(2,"bruce");
          rs=ps.executeQuery();



         /* for (int l = 0; l < 7; l++) {
              column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(l);

              if (l==0) {
                  column.setPreferredWidth(25); 
              }
              if (l == 1||l==2) {
                  column.setPreferredWidth(90); 
              }
              if (l == 3||l==5) {
                  column.setPreferredWidth(145); 
              } 

              if(l==4||l==6) {
                  column.setPreferredWidth(87);
              }
             }
          */

          /*model = new DefaultTableModel(col,7);
          DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new  DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);



            while (rs.next()) 

            {           
            String arr[] ={Integer.toString(rs.getInt("ID")),
            rs.getString("NAME"),rs.getString("AUTHOR"),
            rs.getString("DEPT"),rs.getString("LOC"),
            rs.getString("PUBLISHER"),rs.getString("EDITION")};

            table.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));

                    for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
                       {                        
                        if(k<arr.length&&i<10)      
                {table.setValueAt(arr[k],i,j);
                 table.getColumnModel().getColumn(j).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
                    k++;
                    }   
                            }
                    i++;    }
                                */


             while (rs.next()) {
                String arr[] ={
                  Integer.toString(rs.getInt("ID")),
                  rs.getString("NAME"),rs.getString("AUTHOR"),
                  rs.getString("DEPT"),rs.getString("LOC"),
                  rs.getString("PUBLISHER"),rs.getString("EDITION")
              };
              values.add(arr);
               }




          String[][] data = values.toArray(new String[values.size()][]);
          model = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);
          table.setModel(model);


                  /*   if(rs.next())
                       {
                        String msg = "BOOK FOUND";
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(msg);
                        label.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
                       }
                      else
                      {String msg = "BOOK NOT FOUND";
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(msg);
                    label.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);}
                    */




          System.out.println("hello");


     //table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS)   


                        /*
            JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
            //JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            //panel.add(scroll);
            //getContentPane().add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            */



            JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
            JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            panel.add(scroll);
            getContentPane().add(panel);

            revalidate();
            repaint();


            //JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);

             /*
            JPanel p=new JPanel();
            p.add(table);
            add(p);
          */

        //table.setBounds(200,200,100,100);
        //table.setLocation(200,200);
        //setVisible(true);
        //setSize(900,900);
        //getContentPane().add(pane);
        //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }

                catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed



public static void main(String args[]) {
      /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
       try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
 }
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at lib_ss.NewJFrame2.initComponents(NewJFrame2.java:128)
at lib_ss.NewJFrame2.<init>(NewJFrame2.java:64)
at lib_ss.NewJFrame2$4.run(NewJFrame2.java:364)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. .. 4)

Comment: .. 4) But most importantly, add the `JTable` at application start up, but *set or adjust the **table model*** on button click.

Comment: Do you see the table header and the rows missing or nothing displays

Comment: @AndrewThompson   Well, honestly speaking I didnt understand whatever advise u gave. I am still learning, and have little experience in java gui. It would be great if u specifically describe what to do in order to display the JTable on button click........You can check the jButton2actionPerformed method for that

Comment: @Blip nothing is displayed in this application apart from the gui......but the table was displayed in another simple program where it was added to Jframe

Comment: *"You can check the jButton2actionPerformed method for that"*  **Post an MCVE.**  You can follow the link for that.

Comment: where in you code have you added the `JTable` to your `JFrame`?

Comment: @Blip In jButton2actionPerformed......I tried it there......using different ways but I have commented those lines out as they were not working .....it is at the end of jButton2actionPerformed......can u please suggest how to do it..?

Comment: do you mean to say that after the button is clicked the `JTable` gets added to the `JFrame`?

Comment: yes.........after we click the button in frame the data is retrieved from database and should be displayed in jtable in frame just below the buttons

Comment: after adding the `JScrollPane` containing the `JTable` to the `JPanel` did you call the `revalidate();` and `repaint()` methods?

Comment: @Blip can u tell me how to do it....? The code...?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same in one of my app.

What i did was, I added a `JPanel` on my main panel and then added a `JTable` on that panel using Netbeans GUI.

Initially, hide the `JPanel` containing your table by using `JPanel.setVisible(false);` .. so that it won't show untill the button is pressed.

In button's `actionPerformed` write your code like this:
Let's say if your `JPanel` has name "panel" and `JTable` has name "tab"

```
panel.setVisible(true);
DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel) tab.getModel();

        //your code to get data from database

        while (rs.next()){
            Object rowData= new Object[7]; //as your table has 7 fields/columns
            rowData[0]=rs.getInt("ID");
            rowData[1]=rs.getString("NAME");
            rowData[2]=rs.getString("AUTHOR");
            rowData[3]=rs.getString("DEPT");
            rowData[4]=rs.getString("LOC");
            rowData[5]=rs.getString("PUBLISHER");
            rowData[6]=rs.getString("EDITION");
         }
         model.addRow(rowData);
```

Modify this code according to your need ... it works.

Comment: u mean DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tab.getModel(); .........? U just used Default back there . And please specify the code regarding JPanel and where to add it

Comment: Sorry, yes i meant `DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) tab.getModel();`

I've corrected the code check now.

Comment: @abc you don't need to do anything with JPanel's code .. as you are using Netbeans .. in Netbeans when you drag any component from "swing pallete" to on your form ... code regarding that component is automatically generated at back ... all you need to do is right click on your new inserted JPanel ... change its variable name .. and then use it in your JButton's actionPerformed as i've mentioned above .. let me know if it gives any error

Comment: no, I am using eclipse.....I mentioned that netbeans was just used for GUI design, rest is done on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is after :

```
    //getContentPane().add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You add these lines:

```
    revalidate();
    repaint();
```

also replace the lines

```
            /*
            JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
            //JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            //panel.add(scroll);
            //getContentPane().add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            */
```

with

```
            JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
            JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            panel.add(scroll);
            getContentPane().add(panel);
```

**EDIT AFTER NEW EXCEPTION**

Your main problem lies in this line `javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2742)` in the method `jButton2ActionPerformed`. Studying you code I find that to initialise the `DefaultTableModel` you have used the following line :

```
model = new DefaultTableModel(col,10);
```

Here I cannot find where the variable `col` is initialised in the code you have uploaded. I feel that the `col` may have been initialised to `0`. So this exception occurs as, if the `col` value is `0` then the `DefaultTableModel` will have 0 columns as a result `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will occur when you try to add data to it. Also you have specified that the number of rows of the table is `10`. Now again `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will occur if the `ResultSet` returns more than 10 rows.

My suggestion is that you initialise the `DefaultTableModel` after you have collected all the data from the `ResultSet` object as illustrated below:

1. First you declare and initialise an `ArrayList` say `values` of type `String[]` before the `while` loop retrieving data from you `rs` instance as shown below:

   ```
         ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Inside your `while` loop retrieving data from the `rs` object, instead of adding the data to the `table` variable using `setValueAt` add the data to the `ArrayList` object `values` as illustrated below:

   ```
         while (rs.next()) {
             String arr[] ={
                 Integer.toString(rs.getInt("ID")),
                 rs.getString("NAME"),rs.getString("AUTHOR"),
                 rs.getString("DEPT"),rs.getString("LOC"),
                 rs.getString("PUBLISHER"),rs.getString("EDITION")
             };
             values.add(arr);
         }
   ```
3. Create a new `String[]` variable say `columnNames` to store the name of columns. These names would be displayed as the names of the column in the table's header as illustrated below:

   ```
         String[] columnNames = {
                 "ID","NAME","AUTHOR",
                 "DEPT","LOC",
                 "PUBLISHER","EDITION"
         };
   ```
4. Now initialise the `DefaultTableModel` variable `model` with the constructor `DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data,Object[] columnNames)`. We get the `data` when we call `values.toArray()` which will basically be of type `String[][]`. This is illustrated below:

   ```
         String[][] data = values.toArray(new String[values.size()][]);
         model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
   ```
5. Finally set the `model` variable as the `Model` to the `JTable` as shown.

   ```
         table.setModel(model);
   ```

The Above suggestion not only takes care of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because of your initial code but also takes care of the fact that if the number of rows returned by the `rs` object is more than 10. I hope that this will solve your current problem.

**Your Complete Code**

```
package lib_ss;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String[] col={"ID","NAME","AUTHOR","DEPT","Location","Publisher","Edition"};
    private Connection con;

    public int id=0;

    public void getId(int i){
        id=i;
    }   
    public void connect(){
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","manhattan");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

/**
* Creates new form NewJFrame2
*/
    public NewJFrame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    NewJFrame2(NewJFrame1 aThis) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



/**
* This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
* WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
* regenerated by the Form Editor.
*/
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    public void initComponents() {

        JButton jButton1 = new JButton();
        JButton jButton2 = new JButton();
        JButton jButton3 = new JButton();
        JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();

        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Log Out");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);


        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/lib_ss/mic1.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Search");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton2.setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().add(jButton2);


        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("Previous Records");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton3);


        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/lib_ss/url1.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    public void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        NewJFrame1 frame = new NewJFrame1();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed



    public void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","manhattan");

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from records where stid=?");

            ps.setInt(6,id);

            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()){
                //TODO add functionality.
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    //Search Button
    public void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        int i=0;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","manhattan");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from books where name=? or author=?");

            ps.setString(1,"java");
            ps.setString(2,"bruce");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String arr[] ={
                    Integer.toString(rs.getInt("ID")),
                    rs.getString("NAME"),rs.getString("AUTHOR"),
                    rs.getString("DEPT"),rs.getString("LOC"),
                    rs.getString("PUBLISHER"),rs.getString("EDITION")
                };
                values.add(arr);
            }

            String[][] data = values.toArray(new String[values.size()][]);
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);

//System.out.println("hello");

            JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
            JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            panel.add(scroll);
            getContentPane().add(panel);

            pack();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed


    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
//</editor-fold>

/* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

I have tested it and is working fine without the Database connections and the images.

Comment: without using JScrollPane ?

Comment: @abc I made a mistake about uncommenting  I am correcting it. after that you check the code

Comment: It uses AbsoluteLayout........I did not design the GUI. I am doing the functionality and database part. Plus I dont have much experience in GUI stuff. So please provide the neccessary steps and code. U can take a look at the entire program.....try to read it and U will definitely understand

Comment: Now it is giving exception: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException... where I add data in for loop at: table.setValueAt(arr[k],i,j);                                             Earlier same exception was shown at : column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(l);     but I commented that out........Now exception at:  table.setValueAt(arr[k],i,j);                                            plus a lot others as well in DefaultTableModel, JTable...I dont understand those..should I edit my question and add errors as well.....so that U can see them?

Comment: @abc I have explained the error as I see it and also provided a solution to it. Kindly correct you code as I suggested and if any error occurs post a comment here. I would be glad to help you out.

Comment: It gives error : The constructor DefaultTableModel(Object[ ], String[ ]) is undefined. The error is at model = new DefaultTableModel(values.toArray(),columnNames); And I had col initialized to column names earlier as well.

Comment: @abc I overlooked that part. Now I have corrected the same and now check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77433/discussion-between-abc-and-blip).

Comment: Great effort, but the thing is jtable is only displayed if I dont add background image. And even without it, on clicking search, all buttons move to middle left side of frame and table is displayed at right side. On multiple clicks, multiple tables are displayed, next to each other within same frame.

Comment: Basically you should learn about `LayoutManagers` and how to use it. On multiple clicks, more than one table shows because every time you click you add a new table to the `JFrame` without removing the previous one. So to display only one table you require to either remove the previous table and add new table or replace the existing table with a new table. Moreover *Can not display JTable in JFrame at button click* is solved. For further questions post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the ArrayList

```
 public ArrayList<classExpens> expensList()
{
    ArrayList<classExpens> expensList = new ArrayList<classExpens> ();
    conn=mySqlConnection.ConnectDB();
    String sql="select * from tbl_name";
   try{
       Statement st = conn.createStatement();
       rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

       classExpens expens;
       while(rs.next()){
           expens = new classExpens(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("name"),rs.getString("item"),rs.getFloat("price"),rs.getString("date"));

           expensList.add(expens);
       }

   }
   catch(Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   return expensList;

}
```

Pupulate table from arrayList

```
public void showTable(){
    ArrayList<classExpens> list = expensList();
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblExpens.getModel();
   while(tblExpens.getRowCount()>0)
   {
       ((DefaultTableModel)tblExpens.getModel()).removeRow(0);
   }
   Object[]row = new Object[5];

   for (int i = 0; i <list.size(); i++) {
       row[0]=list.get(i).getid();
       row[1]=list.get(i).getname();
       row[2]=list.get(i).getitem();
       row[3]=list.get(i).getprice();
       row[4]=list.get(i).getdate();



       model.addRow(row);
   }

}
```

Show Data in JForm jtextFields or jlabels

```
public void showItems(int index){
    lblid.setText(Integer.toString(expensList().get(index).getid()));
    txtName.setText(expensList().get(index).getname());
    txtItem.setText(expensList().get(index).getitem());
    txtprice.setText(Float.toString(expensList().get(index).getprice()));

    try{
        java.util.Date addDate= null;
        addDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse((String)expensList().get(index).getdate());
        this.Date.setDate(addDate);
    }
    catch(ParseException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date and Time Error");
    }
}
```